# UltraWinGrid deletes top record rather than the selected one

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, delete-row, ultrawingrid

I've got an ultrawingrid that I can select rows on, and need to be able to delete the highlighted row. At the moment, it calls the database SQL query that I wrote but instead of deleting the record in the row I selected, it deletes the record in the top row instead. Can anybody work out why?

```
    Private Sub btnDeleteIncident_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteIncident.Click

    Try
        Dim rowValue = ugHistory.Selected.Rows

        Dim rowToDelete = ugHistory.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Dim removeIncident As MsgBoxResult
        removeIncident = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete this incident?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")

        If removeIncident = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            Database.deleteIncident(rowToDelete)

            txtClientSave.Text = ""
            rtbProblem.Text = ""
            rtbSolution.Text = ""
            dtpStart.Value = Date.Today
            dtpEnd.Value = Date.Today
            dtpStartTime.Value = DateTime.Now
            dtpEndTime.Value = DateTime.Now
            cboxSolved.Checked = False
            btnUpdate.Hide()
            btnSave.Show()

        ElseIf removeIncident = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            loadIncidents()
        End If

    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No incidents to delete")
    End Try

    loadIncidents()

End Sub
```

Database SQL query;

```
Public Shared Sub deleteIncident(ByVal supportID As Integer)

    Connect()

    Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
    Dc.Connection = Con

    Dc.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM tblIncidents WHERE([supportID] = " & supportID & ")"

    Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Disconnect()

End Sub
```

Comment: Because you are setting rowToDelete to the first row of the grid not to the selected row

Comment: @Steve how do I change this? I've tried using e.Selected.Rows but this didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the value for rowToDelete from the first row of the grid not from the current active row

I suggest you to change this line

```
 Dim rowToDelete = ugHistory.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

to

```
 Dim rowToDelete = ugHistory.ActiveRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Also, it is always better to follow a safe approach when handling reference objects like 'ActiveRow', so before running your code add a test for a valid 
ActiveRow

```
 if ugHistory.ActiveRow Is Nothing Then 
     Return
 End If
 Dim rowToDelete = ugHistory.ActiveRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much, been stuck with this problem for a few hours now. (I'm new to this whole Infragistics thing, sorry!)

Comment: I was always going to accept it as the answer, I just had to wait a few more minutes.